# If I have several wallets with the same address, how to deal with nonces?

Tags: wallets, pending-transactions, nonce, buidler

I access Ethereum from several wallets. Some of the addresses are present in several wallets at once.

I discovered that nonces should always increase. (Right?)

Then if I send transactions from several wallets, the nonces would be incorrect... (so?)

Now I have some pending transactions started from command line (Buidler deployer). Every time I try to deploy the contract, the transaction is stuck. I guessed the deployment stucked once, it causes it to stuck again and again.

How to unstuck it? How to find the pending transactions from my account? (I removed the `deployments/` folder in Buidler, so I can't look there.) How to know nonces of pending transactins? (EtherScan does not show nonce for a pending transaction.)

Comment: Please define *wallet*.

Comment: @goodvibration Saying wallet, I mean any Ethereum client that holds an address. It may be a UI wallet, a Web site, or even a command line utility like Buidler Deployer (the actual software I am having a trouble with).

Comment: Is your transaction still stuck? If you submit multiple transactions they will all remain stuck until the first one is approved. Because you can't skip a nonce. It's probably easiest to cancel or replace your stuck transaction, assuming you have the your private key. Nonces are typically not something you set yourself, but is handled by your wallet or application. You can however override it in most wallet (MyCrypto, MEW, etc.).